# How to recognize a newly inserted android USB device using C++/Windows?

Tags: android, windows, usb, wmi

I am trying to implement a function like this: when an android device is inserted to USB,  get its pid and vid and then use them to do some processing. 
  Now I use WMI to detect USB insertion and deletion. But everytime the device is inserted, my program receives more than one event. That's because the other devices like usb mass-storage card is also detected.
  So from what infomation can I recognize if a newly inserted USB device is an android phone?

Answer (score 0):

I think i find a method to solve this problem.
I listen to the event of win32_PnPEntity creation and the Service property of Win32_pnpEntity can be used to identify the device.